# Why is my loop stopping after if statement?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm very new to coding so please be kind. for an assignment, I need to create Python code that calculates GPA score. In this part, it has to take an input list and convert the letters to their equivalent scores, and print the total score.

It only seems to read the first IF statement and stop after that, instead of repeating as it goes through the input list.

```
letters = ['A', 'B' ,'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'E',]
score = []

length = len(letters)

for score in range(length):
    if letters == ['A']:
        score = score + [4.0]
    elif letters == ['B']:
        score = score + [3.0]
    elif letters == ['C']:
        score = score + [2.0]
    elif letters == ['D']:
        score = score + [1.0]
    elif letters == ['F']:
        score = score + [0.0]


print(score)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Two issues at first glance: First, you're using `score` as both a list as well as an integer in your `for` loop.  You need to use separate variable names.  Second, you're comparing `letters` against `['A']`, `['B']`, etc.  All of those are length 1 whereas `letters` is length 7.  So, none of those comparisons will be true.

Comment: Can you add to the question what the result should look like?

Comment: Unrelated, but if you want to map letter grades to numeric scores, I suggest using a dict, e.g. `letter_score = {"A": 4, "B": 3, ...}` and then `scores = [letter_score[x] for x in letters if x in letter_scores]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python for loop requires a "local variable" acting as each of the elements from a list.  This takes me to the second point: If you're just going over a list with the for loop, then you're not required to store the length of that list in a variable and use `range(length)`. In fact, you should've done exactly that since `score` will just be a number from 0 (unless specified otherwise) to the length of the list.

A more simplified way of iterating over a python list:

```py
for letter in letters:
   if letter == 'A':
      score += 4.0
```

And so on...
I would recommend going over Python lists (which are basically arrays with a lot more built-in functionalities) and their basic operations and syntax.

If you'd like to do it by using a more traditional array syntax:

```py
for i in range(length):
   if letters[i] == 'A':
      score += 4.0
```

Comment: Also change the initialization of `score` to `0` or you get a type error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the proper way to do that, because you use the same variable name (`source`) for two different things.  You need to use a separate variable for the iteration:

```py
for i in range(length):
   if letters[i] == 'A':
      # do something
```

or directly call the variable from the list like this code:

```py
for letter in letters:
    if letter == 'A':
        # do something
```

Comment: I think it should be `if letter == 'A':` (Not my downvote; I think this is closer to fixing the problem than the other answer...)

Comment: Yes, you're right
Thank you for attention

Answer (score 1):

You have reused the variable `score` - once as a list and another time in the for loop as an integer.

Rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = ['A', 'B' ,'C', 'D', 'G', 'E']
score = []

length = len(letters)

for score in range(length):
  if 'A' in letters:
    score = 4.0
  if 'B' in letters:
    score = score + 3.0
  if 'C' in letters:
    score = score + 2.0
  if 'D' in letters:
    score = score + 1.0
  if 'F' in letters:
    score = score + 0.0

print(score)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).